# How to configure comment notification such that no emails are sent in case of spam?

Tags: spam, drupal

I have a drupal 6 site running with blogs on it. I use the comment notify module to implement wordpress-like notification of new comments and the antispam module for keeping the spam off the site.

The issue I have is that commenters get email notification for each comment, including the spam ones, eventhough the antispam module filters those out nicely. My question: how can I configure both modules such that only email notification go out in case of ham comments? Do I need additional modules to make this happen? Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Nick.

Answer (score 1):

Work is being done to make the Antispam and Comment Notify modules play nice together. See these issues on drupal.org: [Antispam "gets" the spam too late](http://drupal.org/node/598772) and [Integrate with the AntiSpam module (presently emailing spam comments to users)](http://drupal.org/node/209641).